# Unable to create .zip files or modify .xpi with file roller in Oneiric

Tags: zip, file-roller

I'm trying to modify a Firefox plugin in .xpi format using file roller. When I try to resave the file after making modifications, I get an error:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Scanning

Updating archive /home/user/Desktop/myplugin.xpi

System error:
E_INVALIDARG
```

If I try to just save it as a .zip instead, I get this error:

```
An error occurred while adding files to the archive.
```

It works fine in maverick and precise, only my oneiric machine is unable to properly save the file. What steps can I take to find the cause of this problem?

Comment: I know File Roller changed the way it identifies archives as of 11.10. I've had to resort to renaming the .xpi to .zip before editing, then rename back to .xpi when done. Annoying, I know.

Comment: It is properly opening the xpi as a zip, the problem is during the process of saving. File roller refuses to save any .zip files, regardless of whether they were an xpi or a newly created archive.

Comment: ah, I understand. I had the same problem with .rar - turns out I had to update the libraries. not sure what applies to Zip with regards to File Roller. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this from the command line successfully with p7zip (which you seem to have installed).

`7z a myplugin.zip * ; mv myplugin.zip myplugin.xpi`

I think the problem is linked to p7zip because it autodetects the type of archive to use from the filename suffix.

Comment: It would work from the command line, but i want to get file-roller working as it should. File-roller is no longer able create or modify zip files in oneiric, but as i stated i can do the same thing in maverick and precise without any errors or issues.